# How can I pass an array and an object at the same time to axios.post

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I know that I can pass an array to axios but because it includes another object not related to the array, how would I go about it? See diagram especially the bottom data for clarification.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYs7T.png)

Comment: Wrap it in another data structure - object or array - whichever is appropriate.

Comment: Would it look something like this?let arrOfObj = [
  { taskname: 'abc, comments: 'dfdfd' },
  { taskname: 'efg', comments: 'gdfd' }, {moreinfo: 'dfdfdfd'}
]

axios.post('url_here',arrOfObj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object wrapper that contains your array and object.

Something like this:

```
{
   myArray: [...],
   myObject: {...}
}
```

Comment: How would I bind this in req.body in the backend? I'm a beginner. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: It depends on what framework you are using in the backend.